# Sending Email, in php through gmail

Tags: php

This is my code, i am very new to php. So, i dnt kno where is the error and why it is not sending emails..
            have the following code, And it is not sending Email. Infact it is only displaying the interface. When i click on button it does nthng. I am working with Wamp Server and dreamweaver. Please if any body could help.

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>EmailForm</title>
   <style type="text/css">
    body {
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     background-color: #FFF;
         }
      body,td,th {
     color: #666;
        }
      </style>
    <?PHP
     if(isset($_POST['Submit1']))
     {$Email=$_POST['Email'];
      $Comments=$_POST['Comments'];

      $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= ‘From: madeeha.rehman5@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

      if(mail('madeeha.rehman5@gmail.com','Hello',$Comments,$headers))
      {echo("Your Email is sent successfully");
        }
        Else
        {echo("Email Sending Failed");}
         }
         ?>
          </head>

       <body text="#999999">
      <form id="EmailForm" name="EmailForm" method="POST"action="file:///E|/Sites/EmailForm.php">
      <table width="450px">
     <tr><td valign="top">
    <label>First Name *</label></td>
    <td valign="top">
    <input name="FName" type="text" size="30px" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td valign="top">
    <label>Last Name *</label></td><td valign="top">
   <input name="LName" type="text" size="30px"/>
     </td></tr>
    <tr><td valign="top">  <label>Email Address *</label></td><td valign="top">
    <input name="Email" type="text" size="30px"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td valign="top">
       <label>Comments *</label></td><td valign="top">
    <textarea name="Comments" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
   <input name="Submit1" type="Submit" value="Submit" style="color:#000" /></td></tr>
   </table>
    </form>


    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Syntax error in line 21:
$headers .= ‘From: madeeha.rehman5@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
should be
$headers .= 'From: madeeha.rehman5@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
also... bad form to mix double quotes and single quotes...

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers .= ‘From: madeeha.rehman5@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
```

You have a `‘` here, which is not something PHP recognizes as quote. Use `'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i over read this, if you read my post earlier, first check whether your smtp is intact GOogles uses ssl, auth and port that should be passed in order to send successfully,

Next your qoutes are mixed with single and double. Try using double qoutes and escaping it instead.

Comment: no, i have not. In php.ini file i have maked changes Like SMTP=smtp@gmail.com, And Send_From=my email id.. Is there still a need to configure

Comment: yes every some smtp including google require you to have auths, i dont know the proper syntax, cause i have not used PHP native mail since. but that is definitly the part why everything goes wrong with your mail. try googling for gmail smtp port and ssl and other and how to use it with mail()

Comment: Sir, Its doing nthng. Means when i click on Submit, All the fields are cleared and No email is sent.

In the php.ini file i have following configuration.
SMTP=localhost
Sentmail_From=madeeha.rehman5@gmail.com..
I save the php.ini file after making these chnges.. But when i Open phpinfo() in the local host.. SMTP =localhost as usual..
And in the Sentmail_From: no value is written..

If there is a problem with my SMTP settings. How to change these. Please could you help me more. I am very new, and i have searched for 2 days on net for this thing, and got more and more confused.. Please help

Comment: hmm i do know other than smtp server Gmail requires, port and SSL Auth,username and password to send email. Have you done that if not ITs one way why you cant send

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your FORM action to ensure that the POST request is being sent to the proper script:

```
<form id="EmailForm" name="EmailForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] refers to the current script.

Comment: It dont worked for me.. The $_Server code as it comes in the address bar, and the page says, Error 403, Forbidden

Comment: Try changing it to: <form id="EmailForm" name="EmailForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">